# Change textfield border colour and also validation @ for the email

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Below is my code which is a client side form validation that only display the validation message but i want it to also change the border color to red when displaying the validation message. I did this (input #register-form {border:1px solid #ca4343;}) but did not work.

Also I what to check for @ in the email required validation

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

  <script>

  // When the browser is ready...
  $(function() {

    // Setup form validation on the #register-form element
    $("#register-form").validate({

        // Specify the validation rules
        rules: {
            name: "required",
            gender: "required",
            address: "required",
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            username: "required",
            password: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 5
            }
        },

        // Specify the validation error messages
        messages: {
            name: "<br>Please enter your name",
            gender: "<br>Please specify your gender",
            address: "<br>Please enter your address",
            email: "<br>Please enter a valid email address",
            username: "<br>Please enter a valid username",
            password: {
                required: "<br>Please provide a password",
                minlength: "<br>Your password must be at least 5 characters long"
            }
        },

        submitHandler: function(form) {
            form.submit();
        }
    });

  });

  </script>

  <form action="./" method="post" id="register-form" novalidate="novalidate">

    <div class="label">Name</div><input type="text" id="name" name="name"  /><br />
    <div class="label">Gender</div><select id="gender" name="gender" />
                                      <option value="">Select One</option>
                                      <option value="Female">Female</option>
                                      <option value="Male">Male</option>
                                   </select><br />
    <div class="label">Address</div><input type="text" id="address" name="address"  /><br />
    <div class="label">Email</div><input type="text" id="email" name="email"  /><br />
    <div class="label">Username</div><input type="text" id="username" name="username"  /><br />
    <div class="label">Password</div><input type="password" id="password" name="password" /><br />
    <div style="margin-left:140px;"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" /></div>

  </form>
```

Comment: This validation add some class to field?

Answer (score 0):

Thats a form, not an input.  Try this:

```
form#register-form {border:1px solid #ca4343;}
```

Or more preferably, assign invalid forms a class, e.g. 'invalid'.  Then your CSS could read:

```
form.invalid {border:1px solid #ca4343;}
```

To only render invalid forms with this border.

Comment: I think he wants to add border to inputs that has some error

Comment: Yes I see now. I've updated to include possible use of a class.

Answer (score 0):

```
  <style>
    .error,#register-form
    {
        border: solid 1px #ca4343
    }
  </style>
```

validation js add new class 'error' you can apply css on this class to show border

Comment: what if I what to check for @ in the email required

Answer (score 0):

Create a new class in your css:

```
input.error {
  border:1px solid #ca4343;
}
```

`.error` is the default error class for the jquery validation plugin

OP added requirement to check for @ in email address:

the line `email: true` in your validate rules checks to see if the email address is a valid email address, and [from the docs](http://jqueryvalidation.org/email-method) this appears to check for an @

Comment: what if I what to check for @ in the email required in the javascript